# Can't deploy to FTP with port 22 in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ftp

I am trying to publish a project in Visual Studio 2019, pointing to port 22 (since I will use a linux environment later)

I followed the steps of:

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239559/error-al-compilar-proyecto-aspx-en-visual-studio and
- https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/a2-hosting-products/windows-hosting/publish-a-site-from-visual-studio-using-ftps

So to summarize:

1. start in administrator mode
2. enable the FTP and IIS options
3. I put in front of my URL both ftps and 990
4. I ping the IP and it is active and without problems

but I still get the same error that I can't connect to the server
Attached the error log

```
11/12/2020 13:36:22
System.AggregateException: Se han producido uno o varios errores. ---> System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Nº de excepción interna 0) System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.<---

System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 22 is SFTP, not FTP(S). The FTPS and SFTP are two completely different protocols. You cannot use the FTP protocol to connect to an SFTP server.

I believe that Visual Studio does not support the SFTP.

See [Visual Studio Publish Website Using SCP/SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549709/850848)